# Do Django and Flask need separate web-servers to run a web application?

Tags: python, flask

I have been reading on their respective website (Django and Flask) about what do they do and what they offer .

I realized the following:

1. Both are web application frameworks: They help and speed up the application dev time.
2. They provide rendering to html from python/html templates (please correct me if I'm wrong)
3. I was able to see that with a minimalist Flask hello world application, the user 
      was able to select the local host port and view the html from browser.

Point 3 led me to believe that Flask comes with its integrated webserver that renders html. Is this capability available in Django? Or does Django require a separate server (Apache for instance) running?

Please help me clarify this confusion. I am trying to understand the difference in the word "web framework"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both Django and Flask use a Python-based server when running in development (Django bundles its own, Flask relies on the third-party Werkzeug library). However, *neither* of these are suitable for running in production: they will need a proper server - suitable candidates include Apache/mod_wsgi, or nginx proxied to gunicorn or uWSGI.

Comment: "neither of these are suitable for running in production" why so?

Comment: Because they're not meant for that. They're not tested for load, stability, or security.

Comment: Ah I see, and is Point 2 correct? Or am I missing something? basically is the intent to use these frameworks is to write webapps and website pages in python?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Yes, of course the point of Python web frameworks is to create web sites.

Comment: my main question was related to python language, is the main purpose to create websites in python? (instead of html, php, js, etc...)

Comment: Python is a general-purpose programming language, you can use it for pretty much anything.  Django and Flask exist entirely to make building web applications using Python easy.